# I am getting my output result in two different lines instead of one

Tags: python, python-3.6

My code is

```
def check(i):
        data = [('ip', i),]
        g=requests.post('http://www.ipvoid.com/ip-blacklist-check/', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)

        string1 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', g.text).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
        r = string1.translate(str.maketrans("\n\t\r", "   "))
        print(str(i)+str(re.findall(r'BLACKLISTED \d+\/\d+',str(r))))

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(10)
    p.map(check, lines)
```

I am getting the result in this form...

```
 212.7.219.223 
['BLACKLISTED 3/96']
212.7.217.119
['BLACKLISTED 5/96']
212.7.219.226
['BLACKLISTED 4/96']
```

What should I add or remove to get in this form...

```
212.7.219.223['BLACKLISTED 3/96'] 
212.7.217.119['BLACKLISTED 5/96']
212.7.219.226['BLACKLISTED 4/96']
```

Comment: I can't see any difference between the outputs

Comment: The difference is the space?

Comment: What is the difference between the two outputs?

Comment: ok so I edited my question, maybe now you could understand my problem

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I cannot find it right now. The problem is `readlines` keeps the newline at the end of each line, so you are printing that as well. Try `str(i).strip()`, or `line.strip()` when you first iterate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String storage in Python Class includes newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980038/string-storage-in-python-class-includes-newline-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines returned by `file.readlines()` include newline characters, so you should strip them if you don't want your IP-addresses to be output with a newline character.

Change:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

to:

```
lines = [l.strip() for l in f]
```

Comment: You do not need `readlines` in your suggestions, you are iterating the list twice that way.

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @blhsing although you could just change `p.map(check, lines)` to 
 `p.map(check, lines.strip())`